# Scraping all data from Reddit searches

Tags: praw

I am using PRAW to scrape data off of reddit. I am using the .search method to search very specific people. I can easily print the title of the submission if the keyword is in the title, but if the keyword is in the text of the submission nothing pops up. Here is the code I have so far.

```
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(----------)
alls = reddit.subreddit("all")

for submission in alls.search("Yoa ming",sort = comment, limit = 5):
     print(submission.title)
```

When I run this code i get

> > Yoa Ming next to Elephant!
> >
> > Obama's Yoa Ming impression
> >
> > i used to yoa ming... until i took an arrow to the knee
> >
> > Could someone make a rage face out of our dearest Yoa Ming? I think it would compliment his first one so well!!!

If you search Yoa Ming on reddit, there are posts that dont contain "Yoa Ming" in the title but "Yoa Ming" in the text and those are the posts I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to update the version of PRAW you are using. Using v6.3.1 yields the expected outcome and includes submissions that have the keyword in the body and not the title.

Also, the `sort=comment` parameter should be `sort='comments'`. Using an invalid value for sort will not throw an error but it will fall back to the default value, which may be why you are seeing different search results between your script and the website.